# Ubuntu dock icons show as black and white, it doesn't look right

Tags: appearance

My Ubuntu Looks Like This:

[image: ubuntu desktop]

Why are the icons showing up as black and white?

Answer (score 10):

You are using the hight contrast theme, open your Apearence setting and change it back to Ambiance (or Radiance).

[image]

Comment: Btw, you will find this in Ubunti 18 under "Universal access"

Answer (score 5):

What you are seeing is a THEME called high contrast.

[image]

Right click on your desktop and set it to ambiance.

Answer (score 0):

N.B. The high contrast setting toggle is no longer in the screen appearance dialogue under my 22.04 Ubuntu. The advice is correct, high contrast is causing the b/w icons. But the toggle is now in a new place, that is, it's found in universal access. I kept poking around the old dialogues where it no longer exists!