# Some app icons in Ubuntu Dock are black & white

Tags: icons, themes, appearance

[image]

I don't know how to name this issue. So I decide to share a screenshot. Is it something serious? I am freaking out. Can you guys help me resolve the issue?

Comment: Oh sorry,edited the post now .Can you see the left panel? Everything is white?

Comment: You can change that to default I guess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu dock icons show as black and white, it doesn't look right](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580182/ubuntu-dock-icons-show-as-black-and-white-it-doesnt-look-right). Same exact problem, you're using High Contrast theme.

Comment: ... and for changing the theme, see this: https://askubuntu.com/q/1030895/480481